# ElasticPress how to Include Meta to the mapping?

Tags: plugins, filters

There's a plugin called [ElasticPress](https://github.com/10up/ElasticPress) it allows to connect an [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/) server to WordPress.
This plugin by default does not [MAP](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) Meta keys (custom fields) that begin with _ (underscore). But it has a filter to add any custom field to the mapping:

[ep_prepare_meta_whitelist_key](https://github.com/10up/ElasticPress/blob/develop/includes/classes/Indexable/Post/Post.php#L422)

My problem is that i don't understand how to use this filter to include my fields into the Mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution 1

I haven't tested the plugin, but based on this code from the link in your question:

```
apply_filters( 'ep_prepare_meta_whitelist_key', false, $key, $post )
```

You can do something like this to explicitly allow a protected/private meta key:

```
add_filter( 'ep_prepare_meta_whitelist_key', function( $allow, $meta_key ){
    $meta_keys = ['_one', '_two', '_etc']; // meta keys you want to allow
    return in_array( $meta_key, $meta_keys );
}, 10, 2 );
```

### Solution 2

Alternatively, looking at [this part](https://github.com/10up/ElasticPress/blob/develop/includes/classes/Indexable/Post/Post.php#L382), you could use the `ep_prepare_meta_allowed_protected_keys` filter to add your custom protected meta keys to the *array of index-able private meta keys*:

```
add_filter( 'ep_prepare_meta_allowed_protected_keys', function( $meta_keys ){
    return array_merge( $meta_keys, ['_one', '_two', '_etc'] );
} );
```

### Summary

If I were you, I'd use the second solution. But it's really up to you. :)

*PS: The code would go in the theme functions file.*

Comment: Thanks i really must learn to read filters. I'm trying to teach myself php but i can't figure this out yet.

Comment: You're welcome. And [this article](https://wpshout.com/wordpress-hooks-actions-filters-work/) may help you to *better* understand the hooks (actions and filters) in WordPress.

Comment: thanks i'll give it a read.